# XSLT 1.0 - How to test an attribute contained in a parameter in an xsl:when statement

Tags: xslt, xpath, saxon

I have an XSLT template that passes a chunk of HTML into parameter.  I need to pass that parameter to another template where it will be transformed one of two ways, depending upon the ID attribute of the top level HTML element contained in the parameter.  Is it possible to test the content of a parameter with Xpath in XSLT 1.0? Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="someID">There could be many child nodes here</div>
```

Here's my XSLT test:

```
<xsl:when test="$content/@id = 'someID'">...</xsl:when>
```

Saxon 6.5.3 fails on this and tells me to switch to use exsl or specify version 1.1 (which has no impact), but I'd love to know if there's a clever way to achieve this using the tools I have in place.

Comment: **1.** How exactly are you passing this parameter? **2.** Please post the **exact** error message.

Comment: The exact error is "To use a result tree fragment in a path expression, either use exsl:node-set() or specify version='1.1' ".  The parameter is declared in the template as follows:   <xsl:param name="content"><xsl:apply-imports/></xsl:param>.  That template then has a choose/when/otherwise basically as shown.

Comment: "*I'd love to know if there's a clever way to achieve this using the tools I have in place.*" Both suggested cures **are** tools that you have in Saxon 6.5. If you're looking for an alternative approach, you will have to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The parameter is declared in the template as follows: `<xsl:param
>   name="content"><xsl:apply-imports/></xsl:param>`.

Strictly speaking, that's a *variable*, not a *parameter*.  And its content is a *result tree fragment*. As the error message says, you must convert it to a *node-set* before you can process it further (in XSLT 1.0).

So do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="content-rtf">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="content" select="exsl:node-set($content-rtf)" />

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$content/div/@id = 'someID'">
        <!-- some result -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- another result -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

after adding:

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
```

to your opening `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag.

---

*Untested because a reproducible example was not provided.*

Comment: After some hacking at that code a bit, I have a working solution. Thanks! I had a feeling XSLT 1.0 couldn't do it alone. Can't wait til I have some time to get everything over to 2.0. Some day...

Comment: You'll never have time to move to XSLT 2.0 if you continue wasting time working around the limitations of XSLT 1.0. The way to find more time is to adopt more productive tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:when test="$content/div[@id = 'someID']">...</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.